# Web workers - can they be set to wait/signal?

Tags: javascript, signals, wait, web-worker

For a web worker, should I think of it as a method that is running for the life of the worker (ie a thread in the Java/C# world)? Or is it more a distinct worker thread that handles method calls in the worker's .js file where each call takes over the thread, pausing any other methods in process in that thread, runs to completion, and then on exit, another of the method calls in the worker are woken and runs?

If it's the first, if I can have a method constantly running, in say a while(true) loop, then how do I have it wait & then signal it?

If it's the second, are there any good resources on how best to use a worker thread for a background process that needs to run at times?

We are writing a word processor and the background thread needs to hold the entire document for the life of the editor. And then when the document is edited, re-calculate the layout. So the data must exist in the worker for the life of the editor. And then, when a change occurs, the layout code is kicked into gear.

**Update:** I've written a bunch of test code and it looks like web workers run as follows - when you call a method, that's the only thing that runs until it returns. You can make other calls and they are queued up, but they do not run until the first method completes.

The good news is no worry's about race conditions, synchronization, etc. The bad news is there's no way to talk to a method in a web worker that is crunching away.

So I'm still not sure - what is the best way to handle this where the background thread needs to d a lot of processing, but needs to be interruptable?

Comment: I'm writing a JavaScript raytracer using webworkers and from what I can tell, you have no control over the "thread" level sleep/wake of the worker.  What I've done so far is queue up messages received by the worker and then every now and then check the messages in the main loop of the worker.  The only advice that I could give would be to have a mechanism in your method to check for messages periodically.

Comment: @zero298 I've just completed some more experimentation and calling setTimeout() will allow another called method to start executing. So this will work. I'll have to have my main loop be a method and on each iteration call it again with a setTimeout() delay of 0, but that will let another method telling me to break to run and set a global var in the worker. More work to do on testing this but this may be the solution.

Comment: I'm glad that that works.  However, right now, I'm trying to understand this question: [Web Worker message processing during long work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20953080/691711). The questioner says that messages cannot be processed during the running of a function (I think) which is strange since I'm pretty sure my tracer listens when I tell it to stop.  Then again, [An effective way to implement semaphore locking in a web worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11007322/691711) suggests something similar.

Comment: For long processes in web worker threads, you would want to divide the work into chunks, say 100 calculations per cycle.  Between each cycle you would check for a message to see if the thread should continue to work.  I am still searching to see if there is a way to block a thread from proceeding until a message is returned / recieved.